# Can I safely delete the Classic System folder when running Lion?

Tags: macos, classic-mac-os

I still have a folder called "System Folder" that belongs to the Classic environment. It takes up almost 400MB on my disk. Since I'm running Lion, can I safely delete the entire folder?

Comment: Wow, you still have that?!  You must have transferred all of your data from machine to machine.  Sometime, you might want to consider a complete reinstall to remove any other oddities that might be lying around.

Answer (score 4):

Considering the Classic environment was phased out versions ago, I think it would be completely safe to delete a folder belonging to the classic environment.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably safe to delete it, unless you're like me.  For example, I still keep a directory of pictures in the Appearance directory that I use for wallpaper.  Old habits die hard. :-) You might want to check if you have anything similarly quirky.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. Everything equivalent that Lion needs resides in the new "System" folder (and others) so you can freely delete your old System Folder.

Answer (score 1):

I did a clean install of Lion and there is no "/System Folder/" there, therefore I believe that you can safely delete the folder "/System Folder/" ***however*** make sure you do not delete the "/System/" folder, otherwise you'll be left with an unbootable system.

(Of course you have a working backup, right ;-?)

Comment: Working backup *and* Carbonite backup. (Been burned before.)